# Failed to build wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am getting the below error while installing wxpython. I had a virtual environment and trying install wxpython.

My system detail is the following.

Linux 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

`(venv) vijay@vijay-System-Product-Name:/docs/source/for_wxpython$ pip install wxpython`

````
  Downloading wxPython-4.1.1.tar.gz (66.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 66.0 MB 4.7 MB/s 
Collecting pillow
  Using cached Pillow-8.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.21.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.7 MB 1.2 MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: wxpython
  Building wheel for wxpython (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ek_7ex87
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxpython
  Running setup.py clean for wxpython
Failed to build wxpython
Installing collected packages: pillow, six, numpy, wxpython
    Running setup.py install for wxpython ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1g_ewvyi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/include/site/python3.8/wxpython                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    Complete output (42 lines):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    running install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    running build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    --skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    
    "/docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/bin/python3" -u build.py build
    Will build using: "/docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/bin/python3"
    3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)
    [GCC 9.3.0]
    Python's architecture is 64bit
    cfg.VERSION: 4.1.1
    
    Running command: build
    Running command: build_wx
    wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode', '--gtk3']
    Configure options: ['--enable-unicode', '--with-gtk=3', '--enable-sound', '--enable-graphics_ctx', '--enable-display', '--enable-geometry', '--enable-debug_flag', '--enable-optimise', '--disable-debugreport', '--enable-uiactionsim', '--enable-autoidman', '--with-sdl']
    /tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/configure --enable-unicode --with-gtk=3 --enable-sound --enable-graphics_ctx --enable-display --enable-geometry --enable-debug_flag --enable-optimise --disable-debugreport --enable-uiactionsim --enable-autoidman --with-sdl
    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for toolkit... gtk
    checking for gcc... no
    checking for cc... no
    checking for cl.exe... no
    configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3':
    configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
    See `config.log' for more details
    Error running configure
    ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "build.py", line 1510, in cmd_build_wx
        wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 372, in main
        exitIfError(wxBuilder.configure(dir=wxRootDir, options=configure_opts),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
        raise builder.BuildError(msg)
    buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error running configure
    Finished command: build_wx (0.363s)
    Finished command: build (0.363s)
    Command '"/docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tta3x8o1/wxpython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1g_ewvyi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /docs/source/for_wxpython/venv/include/site/python3.8/wxpython Check the logs for full command output.
    (venv) vijay@vijay-System-Product-Name:/docs/source/for_wxpython$ ```
````

Comment: »» checking for gcc... no «« : `sudo apt install build-essential` .......... will install g++ and a fully functional gcc , with the required dependencies.

Comment: It did not work. same error.